# Book for artists' renderings of extinct species?

Tags: zoology, palaeontology

I'm looking for a collection, in print or online, of pictures of ancient extinct species (i.e., imagined from fossil remains). Is there a good single resource for this? I'm interested in animals of all kinds, barring dinosaurs, and invertebrates. I'm not interested in recently extinct species but rather the very distant past.

Comment: Any clade you are particularly interested in? Are you interested in plants? In animals? In Vertebrates? In mammals? Are you interested in a particular mass extinction event? Past 100,000 years or older like dinosaurs (230-65 millions years) or even older? You don't necessarily have to narrow down your question but you might be disappointed to get drawings of ferns, of gigantic dragonflies or of dinosaurs if you were expecting mamooths, saber toothed cats and dodo birds.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I should have been more specific. I'm interested in animals of all kinds, barring dinosaurs, and invertebrates. I'm not interested in recently extinct species but rather the very distant past.

Answer (score 1):

With a quick search I was surprise that I could only find

- [Animals of a Bygone Era: An Illustrated Compendium](https://www.amazon.ca/Animals-Bygone-Era-Illustrated-Compendium/dp/0399578528/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1503245431&sr=8-1&keywords=extinct%20species%20drawing)
- [Extinct Species](https://www.amazon.ca/Extinct-Species-Tamara-Green/dp/0717255727/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1503245406&sr=8-3&keywords=extinct%20species)
- [Extinct Animals of the British Isles](https://www.amazon.ca/Extinct-Animals-British-Justin-Gerlach/dp/1326086030/ref=sr_1_8?ie=UTF8&qid=1503245406&sr=8-8&keywords=extinct%20species)
- [Extinct Birds](https://www.amazon.ca/Extinct-Birds-Julian-P-Hume-ebook/dp/B073RZ2SBL/ref=sr_1_12?ie=UTF8&qid=1503245406&sr=8-12&keywords=extinct%20species)

It looks like there is an open niche to someone who like biology of extinct species and illustrations!

Note all will be of interest to you. None of them seem to offer good quality computer based illustration but rather pencil drawings.